# change in app purchase price for reviewers?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app has quite a few in-app-purchase items.

I'd like give one or two IAP items for free when a user leaves a review in the app store.
(If it is hard to prove someone wrote a review is hard, I can give those items to whoever clicked 'leave a review' button from my app to go to the web)

Still, how do I lower the price for IAP items for certain users?

Comment: How do u trigger the review process? with a third party lib like iRate?

Comment: I havent looked at how would I trigger it, I assume giving url for the review page would be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't lower the price for IAP items: the price are fixed for a certain amount of time to all your users. You have set-up those prices in `iTunesConnect`.

One solution I have in mind would be to send `PROMO code` to the people who have sent you their review. This [page](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_generate_promo_promotional_code_iphone_app.html) explain how to generate promo codes and their limitations (like 50 promotions codes per version of your app). You won't be able to lower the price of ur IAP items though with this solution. The other thing to consider is that you won't have any control for people who go directly to the review page without being redirected through your app.

Comment: I guess I can just unlock the items when user hit 'i'll review it' button. Thanks for suggestions